# How to set 3G as network mode in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: networking

I used to set data connection in Android to 3G mode only in network settings, network mode. In Windows Phone 8.1, there is Cellular+ SIM, Highest Connection Speed, where I selected 3G but it still connects through Edge displaying E, probably because of poor 3G coverage. However, I don't want it to play cute and switch connection to 2G. Is there a way to set network mode solely to 3G in Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: So you want the Phone to connect to 3G or not at all if the coverage is not good enough?

Comment: Are you really trying to set a *minimum* network speed? That could leave you in cases when you *could* have a connection, but you'd rather you didn't?

Comment: @Thomas, you got it. That option exists in Android.

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes I guess so. A minimum network speed option would be cool, if any, so that I could select 3G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible, as the selecting the option 3G will only limit the maximum speed. Unfortunately you can't say "at least 3G or not at all" at the moment.

You should consider requesting this feature on http://windowsphone.uservoice.com

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post on xdadevelopers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2738336) it is possible to achieve. You need to install a Vietnam's firmware and enter the code ##3282# in the dial screen. Note that it refer to the preview for developers program, which are used to get very stable versions of the upcoming OS update. If you want, try it by your own risk.

Comment: Thanks. But the link you gave seems invalid, giving a 404.

Comment: I've fixed the link.

Comment: @Indrek the link has been fixed.